# position android widgets

Tags: android, android-layout

How to place a widget exactly at the required location, say for example in relative layout, I am trying to place two buttons one below another and then increase width of button, but using drag and drop in eclipse, it resizes other widgets in the layout. In short, I want to place widget independent of parent widgets, anywhere in layout to visualize the UI I want to design. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RelativeLayout and margins to position precisely.  For example:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Use android:layout_marginLeft for X and android:layout_marginTop for Y -->
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also use an AbsoluteLayout, which is actually probably more suited for this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Use android:layout_x for X and android:layout_y for y -->
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="50dp" android:layout_y="50dp" android:text="Positionable" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Jim, I tried your first option, along with current widget which I am trying to alter, I can see its parent widget moving too. How can I fix it? Your second option uses a obsolete method.

Comment: Can you post your xml or a piece that represents the problem if you can't show the code?  I'm not really sure what the problem is.